# Different output when textarea contains line break

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, line-breaks

I have a textarea, where the user can write his name.

```
<h2><textarea name="txt_company" rows="5" id="company_text"></textarea><textarea name="txt_visitor" rows="5" id="visitor_text">
</textarea><textarea name="text_rp" rows="5" id="rp_text">
</textarea></h2>
```

When pressing the button

```
<input type="submit" class="wmfg_btn" name="submit_form" id="submit_form_btn" value="Code generieren..." onclick="generatecode();" />
```

the output with the entered name will be displayed as an alert:

```
function generatecode() {
        var text_company = document.getElementById("text_company").value;
        var text_visitor = document.getElementById("text_visitor").value;
        var text_rp = document.getElementById("text_rp").value;
        alert('Blablabla' + text_company + 'blablabla' + text_visitor + 'blablabla' + text_rp + 'blabla.');
    }
```

Now, my problem is, that if the user puts in for example 2 names with a line break between, my output should be expanded with `<br>` after each variable.

Like for example:

```
alert('Blablabla' + text_company + '**ADDITION**blablabla' + text_visitor + 'blablabla' + text_rp + 'blabla.')
```

But im stuck right now, I cant find a good solution...
Im open for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add `\n` as a line break for the entry.

```
function generatecode() {
    var text_company = document.getElementById("text_company").value + " \n"; // added line break
    var text_visitor = document.getElementById("text_visitor").value + " \n"; // added line break
    var text_rp = document.getElementById("text_rp").value + " \n"; // added line break
    alert('Blablabla' + text_company + 'blablabla' + text_visitor + 'blablabla' + text_rp + 'blabla.');
}
```

EDIT: Added `\n` to all "text_' variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method indexOf to detect if the value of the textarea contains "\n" and according to the result (-1 if no line break) you can add or not a line break to the value of the textarea.

```
<textarea name="test" rows="5" id="test"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="alertValue()" />
<script>
    function alertValue(){
        var test = document.getElementById("test").value;
        if(test.indexOf("\n") != -1){
            test += "\n";
        }
    }
</script>
```

In addition, take care of your textearea ids: `text_company` != `company_text`.

Comment: helped me a lot! thx!

And yeah, no worries, this was on purpose :)